# How to capture WM_SHOWWINDOW command in MFC

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am trying to do some action whenever dialog box is Shown. Its like we have modalless dialog, and we are hinding/showing the dialog on some button click. But we we need to perfomr some action whenever dialog is shown. I have added the WM_SHOWWINDOW message but control is not coming inside of OnShowWindow(BOOL bShow, UINT nStatus) function.

We are using ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) and ShowWindow(SW_SHOW) function to hide/show dialog box 
Please suggest some pointer how to achieve that.

Thanks in advance

Mukesh

Comment: Do not hide dialog boxes, there won't be any window left in your app that the user can interact with.

Answer (score 3):

I tested this with notepad and Spy++ with the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int CALLBACK WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow ) {
  HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, L"Untitled - Notepad");
  ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_HIDE );
  Sleep(4000);
  ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );
  return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

For hiding the window, you should be getting WM_SHOWWINDOW, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, then finally WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

For showing the window, the target did not receive WM_SHOWWINDOW, but still got WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING and WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED.

You could handle WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED and check the flags in WINDOWPOS for SWP_HIDEWINDOW/SWP_SHOWWINDOW.